# Section list with collapsible section header in react-native

Tags: react-native, react-native-sectionlist, react-native-collapsible

**I am using react-native version 0.61.5. I want to do a section list with a collapsible header in react-native as shown in the below image.**

Here is my API data formate

```
data:[
  {
    shift_name:'Day',
    data:[
    {
      id:'1',
      fullname: "seela",
      inspection_date: "2020-06-10T04:45:32Z",
      issues: 1,
      response:{
        shift_name:'Day'
      }
     }
    ]
  },
  {
    shift_name:'Afternoon',
    data:[
      {
        id:'2',
        fullname: "Raju vijayan",
        inspection_date: "2020-06-9T04:45:32Z",
        issues: 3,
        response:{
          shift_name:'Afternoon'
        }
      },
      {
        id:'3',
        fullname: "Pratap P",
        inspection_date: "2020-06-8T04:45:32Z",
        issues: 2,
        response:{
          shift_name:'Afternoon'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

[image]

**When I click on header content should expand and collapse. How can I do it in react-native?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Animated Accordion/ Drawer/ Drop-down/ Collapsible-card in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67060475/animated-accordion-drawer-drop-down-collapsible-card-in-react-native)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Make each item a component.

Use **Layoutanimation** for your requirement.

Use a state to manage the states of item. ie, open and close.

```
const [open, setopen] = useState(false);
```

Initially, the item is in a close state.

Display data according to the condition.

Logic: you only need to specify the height only if the item is closed.

```
!open && { height: 40 }
```

if it's not open, give the header height. Otherwise, it will occupy the height it needs.

## **Full code**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
  View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, LayoutAnimation, Platform, UIManager,
} from 'react-native';

if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
  if (UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental) {
    UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental(true);
  }
}


export default function TestFile() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Item />
      <Item />
      <Item />
      <Item />
      <Item />
      <Item />
    </View>
  );
}


function Item() {
  const [open, setopen] = useState(false);
  const onPress = () => {
    LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.easeInEaseOut);
    setopen(!open);
  };
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.item, !open && { height: 40 }]} onPress={onPress} activeOpacity={1}>
      <Text>Header</Text>
      {open && (
        <View>
          <Text> SOME DATA</Text>
          <Text> SOME DATA</Text>
          <Text> SOME DATA</Text>
          <Text> SOME DATA</Text>
          <Text> SOME DATA</Text>
          <Text> SOME DATA</Text>
        </View>
      )}
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: 50,
  },
  item: {
    width: '100%',
    borderWidth: 1,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    overflow: 'hidden',
    paddingVertical: 10,
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});
```

## **Result**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your data is stored in state, right? So I have an approach which is add an additional property in each of your data named `isCollapsed` with initial value is `true`

When a header of an item is clicked, you set `isCollapsed` of that item to the opposite value.

Then the visibility status of the collapsible view of each item is depend on `isCollapse` property.

That my solution :) Hope that help :)

Please check my code:

```js
renderItem = (item, index) => {
      return (
          <View>
              // Header content
              <TouchableOpacity
                  onPress={() => {
                      let { data } = this.state;
                      data = data.map((item, key) => {
                          if (key === index) {
                              item.isCollapsed = !item.isCollapsed;
                          }
                          return item;
                      });
                      this.setState({
                          data,
                      });
                  }}
              >
              </TouchableOpacity>

              // Collapsible content
              <View style={{
                  display: (item.isCollapsed) ? 'flex' : 'none'
              }}>

              </View>
          </View>
      );
  }
```